# Remove anchor(back button) on basis of rel attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two back button generated but i need only one. i want to remove the button with rel='2'. below are the buttons

```
 <a href="#" class="prev-tab mover" rel="1">BACK</a>
 <a href="#" class="prev-tab mover" rel="2">BACK</a>
```

i am trying to remove it through jquery like

```
 $('.prev-tab a[rel=2]').remove();
```

but i am not getting the result can any one correct my line of code. thanxs in advance for any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$('a.prev-tab[rel=2]').remove();
```

Based on your code:

```
$('.prev-tab a[rel=2]').remove(); // You are looking for  an anchor tag with rel=2 who is a descendant of an element with class `prev-tab`
```

if you know that `rel` is going to be specific in your page on anchors `.prev-tab` then you can just use `$('.prev-tab[rel=2]')`. `.prev-tab[rel=2]` or just `a[rel=2]`  is better than `a.prev-tab[rel=2]`

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code.

```
$(".prev-tab").each(function(){
if($(this).attr(rel)==2)
{
$(this).remove();
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work (if no other anchor tag is not having 'rel' attribute you want to remove)..

```
$('a[rel=2]').remove();
```